# How to implement delay in android?

Tags: android, delay

I want to print sequential numbers every 2 seconds when I press button. I used following code:

```
int j=0;
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            c=Calendar.getInstance();
            Delay(2 ,c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            if(j++<5)
              t.setText("number "+j);

            }

    });

public void Delay(int p,int q){

    int z=0;

    while(z<p){
        c=Calendar.getInstance();
        i= c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        z=i-q;
    }

    return ;
}
```

but this code prints "Number 5" at the end of 10 seconds directly.
How can I print "Number 1", "Number 2", "Number 3"....sequentially every 2 sec.

Comment: use your printing code in loop while loop

Comment: read there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702298/android-how-to-run-an-asynctask-every-second

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread for ten seconds... You mustn't do that. You should use an AsyncTask / use a new thread, check this link. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you're doing this on UI thread, you'll be blocking the UI thread for 10 seconds.  It's much better to have a separate thread to do this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for(int j=1; j<=5; i++) {
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() { t.setText("number " + j); }
                    });
                    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

This code starts a new thread (thus not blocking the UI), which iterates from 1 to 5 outputting the number (on UI thread, as it's changing the UI) and then sleeps for 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Runnable to post to a handler bound to the UI thread for your app rather than sleep or delay.  If you sleep or delay in your `onClick()` method, you are blocking the UI thread and it will make your UI unresponsive.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {
    ...
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(this);
    private int     mNumber = 0;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mNumber++;
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                t.setText("number: " + mNumber);
            }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) for this..you just have to define the amount of time and how often you want to update. You just have to adjust the logic a bit to do print the numbers upward.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    new CountDownTimer(60000, 2000) {

       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
       }

       public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
       }
    }.start();
}
});
```